# is it possible to create AWS s3 bucket with null region

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Am seeing a Java stacktrace error that implies there is an S3 Bucket with null region.

Is this possible?  I tried to re-create the error and a null-region s3 bucket with no success.

```
com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: The bucket is in this region: null.Please use this region to retry the request (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 301; Error Code: PermanentRedirect; Request ID: EA0959BA1B1D56A7)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1372)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:919)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:697)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:449)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:411)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:360)
        at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:3962)
        at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.getBucketPolicy(AmazonS3Client.java:2544)
        at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.getBucketPolicy(AmazonS3Client.java:2504)
```

Comment: Why do you want to do that?  If you don't care about the region, either use createBucket("bucketName") or createBucket("bucketName", Region.US_Standard).  Why do you want to pass null?

Comment: It's an error that I'm seeing.  I only want to reproduce the error so that I can fix it.

Comment: Check to see if (1) you have the environment variable AWS_DEFAULT_REGION set to nothing and/or (2) ~/.aws/config has the region set to nothing.

Comment: I agree that jcalloway's question is fair and useful to others. The exception message from the AWS SDK is misleading: "The bucket is in this region: null" A reasonable person would have expected the error message to include the actual region. IMO this warrants a bug report over at https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/issues

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I was able to reproduce this error.
It occurs when your AmazonS3Client is set to a different region then the bucket you are calling.

```
def s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(new BasicAWSCredentials("accessKey", "secretKey"))
s3Client.setRegion(com.amazonaws.regions.Region.getRegion( Regions.AP_NORTHEAST_1) )
def policy = s3Client.getBucketPolicy('joshuacalloway-us-east-1-bucket')
println policy
```

--> results in

```
Result: com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: The bucket is in this region: null. Please use this region to retry the request (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 301; Error Code: PermanentRedirect; Request ID: 5F941FB57305BDEC), S3 Extended Request ID: xajT6YydJU+EfoOFWtD4SFiaxS7zoOUS9OKAmFVq/CECmoNuCbcDu4q7z4L+kztbyrMxb5c/Bcw=
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1543)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:1181)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:962)
```

Answer (score 3):

No you can't - A bucket **must** be created within an existing region, using this information is also how you retrieve objects from your bucket

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingBucket.html

> When you create a bucket, you provide a name and AWS Region where you want the bucket created
>
> If you don’t specify a region, Amazon S3 creates the bucket in the US East (N. Virginia) Region.

you can enable [Cross-Region Replication](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/crr.html) if you want your bucket to be automatically replicated in different region

Comment: I'm guessing that it could be a bucket that was created long time ago, when AWS allowed a person to create a bucket with no region

Comment: @jcalloway I created a bucket today and it didn't ask for region. Moreover when I tried to select a region from the S3 console drop-down menu, it says "S3 doesn't require region selection".

Comment: @Prashant when you create a bucket it asks you for the region, if you go to console, you have a dropdown with the available region, if you do from CLI either you have region defined in your profile else you **must** pass the region to the CLI when creating bucket

Answer (score 1):

This is misleading error. I also faced this issue but identified it to be a Policy which had a spelling mistake with the bucket name.   e.g. instead of mybucket, i had mentioned mybuckt.

```
"Resource": [
     "arn:aws:s3:::mybuckt",
     "arn:aws:s3:::mybuckt/*"
]
```

Once I corrected it, the issue got resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your env and the s3 buckets are in the same region. If not then provide some bucket policies to make your bucket accessible from the other region.